# Ubuntu 16.04 - Mac OS X clients can't edit files from other users on samba share

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I have a strange problem with my Samba Share. Clients with Mac OS X can create new folders and files, however they can't edit files which another user created.

For example:

User A with the username usera created a mockup in Photoshop and saves it on the server. The output of `getfacl` will be:

```
# owner: usera
# group: smbgrp
user::rw-
group::rwx
group:smbgrp:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--
```

Now User B wants to make a minor edit on the Photoshop mockup. He opens the mockup, makes his changes and clicks on save to override the mockup. However he can't override the mockup because Photoshop tells him that he don't have any write access. The primary group of User A and User B are both `smbgrp`. As you can see above the group has full access to the file.

I really can't figure out why it doesn't work.

My Setup is the following:

**Server:**

Ubuntu 16.04.2

**Samba:**

Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu

**Filesystem for the Share:**

ZFS (I have set posixacl with `zfs set acltype=posixacl naspool/data`)

**Output from `testparm -s`:**

```
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
rlimit_max: increasing rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384)
Processing section "[netlogon]"
Processing section "[sysvol]"
Processing section "[fileshare]"
Loaded services file OK.
Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

# Global parameters
[global]
    realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    server role = standalone server
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%I
    max log size = 0
    unix extensions = No
    load printers = No
    printcap name = /dev/null
    cache directory = /var/cache/samba/runlocks
    dns forwarder = 192.168.0.1
    idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    inherit permissions = Yes
    inherit acls = Yes


[netlogon]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/example.com/scripts
    read only = No
    browseable = No


[sysvol]
    path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
    read only = No
    browseable = No


[fileshare]
    comment = Fileshare for example.com
    path = /mnt/data/data01_files
    read only = No
    create mask = 0664
    force create mode = 0664
    directory mask = 02775
    directory mode = 02775
    force directory mode = 02775
    nt acl support = No
    veto oplock files = /*.mdb/*.MDB/*.dbf/*.DBF/
    kernel oplocks = Yes
    dos filetime resolution = Yes
    fake directory create times = Yes
    vfs objects = recycle
    recycle:directory_mode = 660
    recycle:keeptree = yes
    recycle:versions = true
    recycle:repository = /var/trash
    acl_xattr:ignore system acls = yes
    fruit:encoding = private
    fruit:locking = none
    fruit:metadata = netatalk
    fruit:resource = file
```

**Clients:**

Mac OS X 10.11.6

**Users:**

All Users have the primary group `smbgrp`.

All Users have an own account on the Ubuntu server. Additionally they where added to Samba with `smbpasswd -a USERNAME`.

The Users connect with the smb:// protocol.

I hope you can help me with this problem.

Regards,

Cyrus180